# where can i find the byteswap macros i.e. Endian32_Swap() in IOS4.3?

Tags: ios, endianness

I'm porting a project from mac os to iphone os. I can't seem to find Endian32_Swap() etc anywhere.

thanks,

oli

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't have byteswap.h and Endian32_Swap() etc

i'm using

```
#include <libkern/OSByteOrder.h>

OSSwapInt32(x)
```

instead